# yo polymer building error

Tags: polymer, yo

I have just updated my Polymer development tools and I get some errors, although everything was working fine before. Here is what I get when trying '*yo polymer*' in the console :

> /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-polymer/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:444
>     this.env.sharedFs.on('change', writeFiles);
>                       ^
>   TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'
>       at run (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-polymer/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:444:21)
>       at Environment.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:330:20)
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:91:9
>       at Environment.resolver.lookup (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js:50:12)
>       at init (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:66:7)
>       at pre (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:53:3)
>       at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:155:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>      at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

Or when I type '*yo*' in the console and choose '*polymer*' :

> /usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:9379
>           throw e;
>                 ^
>   TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'
>       at run (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-polymer/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:444:21)
>       at Environment.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:330:20)
>       at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/routes/run.js:20:11)
>       at Router.navigate (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/router.js:36:30)
>       at PromptUI.completed (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/routes/home.js:76:20)
>       at PromptUI.onCompletion (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:69:10)
>       at AnonymousObserver.Rx.AnonymousObserver.AnonymousObserver.completed (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1965:12)
>       at AnonymousObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onCompleted (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1902:14)
>       at AutoDetachObserverPrototype.completed (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:9397:23)
>       at AutoDetachObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onCompleted >(/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1902:14)

Any idea on what when wrong with the updates (no error thrown).

Thanks for reading and all the best.

PS : I am running on

- Fedora 20
- npm 2.5.1
- yo 1.4.5
- generator-polymer 0.7.0
- gem 2.1.11
- sass 3.4.12
- compass 1.0.3

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention my bower and grunt versions :
bower 1.3.12
grunt 0.4.5
grunt-cli 0.1.13

Comment: Created an issue about this: https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/762

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update yo (npm install -g yo). I had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. After having broken several times my `npm` with `npm update -g`, I used to rely on this script : 
`#!/bin/sh
 
set -e
set -x

for package in $(npm -g outdated --parseable --depth=0 | cut -d: -f2)
do
npm -g install "$package"
done`. Seems like I have to go back to the old `npm install -g` to clearly get latest updates. Everything is fine now thanks.